# Stepping into C++ functions from external Python app while debugging

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, c++, debugging

I just wanted to see how to step into the C++ class QgsVectorLayer()'s methods from the python call to QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(),'foo','postgres').  I'm trying to debug and it trying to step into the function doesn't work.

How do I debug an external Python app by stepping into the underlying SIP/C++ code?

Are there instructions anywhere?

Or even simply remote debugging the python app by attaching, using visual studio, on a specific QGIS binary...?